# When assigning text to a label I get an Object Reference Not Set To And Instance of an Object

Tags: c#, asp.net, label

I built a simple custom control that contains labels. In the codebehind of the custom control I am trying to set the text of the label but I get a null reference error. Any ideas?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DisplayCustomerReviews", connection);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


        XmlReader reader = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader();


        //while (reader.Read())
        while (!reader.EOF)
        {
            reader.ReadToFollowing("review");

            reader.MoveToAttribute("Name");
            string Name = reader.Value;

            reader.MoveToAttribute("Message");
            string Message = reader.Value;

            reader.MoveToAttribute("Rating");
            string Rating = reader.Value;

            reader.MoveToAttribute("Date");
            string Date = reader.Value;

            reader.MoveToAttribute("Time");
            string Time = reader.Value;

            CreateReviewPanel(Name, Message, Rating, Date, Time);

        }

        reader.Close();
        connection.Close();
    }

    private string GetConnectionString()
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SQLConn"];
    }

    private void CreateReviewPanel(string Name, 
                                   string Message, 
                                   string Rating, 
                                   string Date, 
                                   string Time)
    {

        // need to check against nulls or empty strings to avoid 
        // extra reviewPanel being created at end of XML read. 
        if (Name != "") 
        {

            Guid panelID = Guid.NewGuid();

            Panel reviewPanel = new Panel();
            reviewPanel.ID = panelID.ToString();

            nameLabel.Text = Name;

            messageLabel.Text = Message;

            dateLabel.Text = Date;

            timeLabel.Text = Time;

            switch (Rating)
            {
                case "1":
                    ratingImage.ImageUrl = "~/images/one-star.gif";
                    break;
                case "2":
                    ratingImage.ImageUrl = "~/images/two-stars.gif";
                    break;
                case "3":
                    ratingImage.ImageUrl = "~/images/three-stars.gif";
                    break;
                case "4":
                    ratingImage.ImageUrl = "~/images/four-stars.gif";
                    break;
                case "5":
                    ratingImage.ImageUrl = "~/images/five-stars.gif";
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where it says 'nameLabel.Text = Name' is where the error occurs, and subsequently for all the other assignments.

Comment: Your label is null, are you assigning text too early in the life cycle? Post the code where you are getting this error.

Comment: Provide some code, otherwise it will be difficult to identify the problem.

Comment: +1 we can't really help until we see code!

Comment: This wont fix your problem but use `String.IsNullOrEmpty(Name)` instead of `Name != ""` so your code matches the description next to it.

Comment: How are you loading the control, depending on how the control is being made it may not run through full life cycle and therefore your objects will not be initialised and therefore null.

Comment: Is this the code-behind for the custom control? Is the custom control a Review Panel or does it contain Review Panels? It looks like you are attempting to set the same label text multiple times. I don't see where a new name/message/etc. is being created for each review. Instead of creating a new Panel, shouldn't you be creating a new ReviewPanel and setting its control fields to the values?

Comment: Kind of need to see the XML you're reading too.  Noticed review is camelCase but all attributes are PascalCase, is that intentional?  Also, what happens if you comment out your code and in page_load just say nameLabel.Text = "XYZ"; does it null ref there too?  Without seeing your actual component instantiation can't tell if it doesn't like the label or what you are assigning it to.

Comment: When I had this code in the codebehind of default.aspx it worked perfectly fine. I was able to assign text to the labels exactly the same as I am attempting to do in the custom control's codebehind...however after moving the code over, I get the null reference.

Comment: So why are you looping through reviews and setting the same controls over-and-over again to different values? Are you wanting to display only the last review? If so, why are you even reading the others?

Comment: And why are you creating a new Panel for each review? You are not adding the panel to any screen, nor are you creating any controls within it, so all these extra panels will just get garbage collected away anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

Is nameLabel an ID of a control on the page?  If not, you need to do:

```
Label nameLabel = this.lblSomeControlID;
```

In order for nameLabel to reference anything valid.

Comment: yes, the nameLabel is a control on the page of the custom control.

Comment: The fact that this code compiles means that `nameLabel` must refer to something. If it is an unitialized field, then creating a new variable to reference that unitialized value is not going to solve anything.

Comment: What do you mean "on the page of the custom control."  Can you post some markup too?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It was code in my default.aspx.cs that was trying to grab each custom control as it was created and add it as a control to another panel on the default page. The problem is when the XMLreader makes one more loop and returns nulls. The custom control codebehind cannot assign nulls. I appreciate everyone's comments...as convoluted as this may have been.

Answer (score -1):

The code should look something like this, probably:

```
    private void CreateReviewPanel(string Name, string Message, string Rating, string Date, string Time)
    {

        if (Name != "") //need to check against nulls or empty strings to avoid extra reviewPanel being created at end of XML read.
        {

            Guid panelID = Guid.NewGuid();

            ReviewPanel reviewPanel = new ReviewPanel();
            reviewPanel.ID = panelID.ToString();

            reviewPanel.nameLabel.Text = Name;

            reviewPanel.messageLabel.Text = Message;

            reviewPanel.dateLabel.Text = Date;

            reviewPanel.timeLabel.Text = Time;

            switch (Rating)
            {
                case "1":
                    reviewPanel.ratingImage.ImageUrl = "~/images/one-star.gif";
                    break;
                case "2":
                    reviewPanel.ratingImage.ImageUrl = "~/images/two-stars.gif";
                    break;
                case "3":
                    reviewPanel.ratingImage.ImageUrl = "~/images/three-stars.gif";
                    break;
                case "4":
                    reviewPanel.ratingImage.ImageUrl = "~/images/four-stars.gif";
                    break;
                case "5":
                    reviewPanel.ratingImage.ImageUrl = "~/images/five-stars.gif";
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```